# ASP NET Web Api validation hangs for minuttes

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a simple web api which takes one parameter during post:

```
[HttpPost]
public ResultItem<Reports> SubmitReports(Reports reports)
```

The report model contains simple properties, except one which is a bit complex (inhertance, but not much data). When this property is null, my api gets called without any issues, but when it contains a value the api hangs for several minutes before finally arriving at my method.

I have pin-pointed the issue to happen at some point related to validation (Deserialization works fine). If I disable validation, my api gets called straight away with a completely valid object:

```
config.Services.Clear(typeof(ModelValidatorProvider));
```

I have not annotated the Reports object with any validation attributes. Somehow the validation is not happy with my object, but it does not throw any exception it only hangs for minutes.

How can I proceed to find the root cause of my problem?

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I'm getting the same issue. Rather than disable validation entirely, I've commented out or manually skipped over the Validate method call. I tried putting it in a try catch, but unfortunately I never hit the catch or the line after the try ends. I'm using FluentValidation, but I tried commenting out the line that set up Fluent as the default validator and I still get the same issue.

Edit: I figured it out. The Validate() method is hanging when I pass it a proxy from EF. I was retrieving the entity I wanted, patching it, and validating it, but it wasn't an actual entity, it was the dynamic proxy that was being validated and that causes the API to hang; I suspect it was validating everything in the DB by iterating over references, but I'm not sure. In any case, I just disabled ProxyCreationEnabled and validate no longer hangs.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this. I have not found the cause of my issue yet. I will post it if I find out.